# NotePad++ Get words with REGEX Pattern of Delimiters

Tags: notepad++, search, regex

I am currently using this REGEX to get whole words with a prefix of PRE_

```
\b(PRE_)\S*
```

This works fine for most cases, but I would like to handle cases when a special character is part of the word, such as a period, comma or other special character . , ; - { } ( ) [ ]

For example, the words here:

```
PRE_samplewordwithoutdelimiter
PRE_sampleword.otherwordsnotincluded;
PRE_Sampleword{}...deleted
PRE_complexword()a.;.is deleted
Somewords ahead PRE_sometext() ending in other words
Words with bracket [PRE_brackettext] are deleted
PRE_sampleword is spaced out so deleted
sampleword.PRE_deleted;
notdeleted.notdeleted.PRE_
```

I would like only to find the first part of a delimited word. So I can delete or replace the word. So, in the case of replacing all PRE_ prefixed words in this scenario with "" as the text, I would get:

```
<DELETED>
<DELETED>.otherwordsnotincluded;
<DELETED>{}...deleted
<DELETED>()a.;.is deleted
Somewords ahead <DELETED>() ending in other words
Words with bracket [<DELETED>] are deleted
<DELETED> is spaced out so deleted
sampleword.<DELETED>;
notdeleted.notdeleted.<DELETED>
```

I was trying different REGEX, but nothing really matches entirely correct throughout the samples. Something like the following doesn't work:

```
\b(PRE_)\S*(?:[;]|[.][-])$
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Instead of including all non-space character (`\S` in your first regex) after `PRE_`, simply state all "non-delimiters" in your search and it should do.

The following works for all of your example, by replacing `\S` with `[A-Za-z]`:

```
\bPRE_[A-Za-z]*
```

If you wish to include numeric, hyphen (`-`) and underscore (`_`) you can use the following instead:

```
\bPRE_[-A-Za-z0-9_]*
```

**Method 2**

Otherwise, you could modify your `\S` into "anything but `\s` and other delimiters such as `.`, `,`, `;`, `{`. `}`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` (and any others at your wish)"  In that way your regex becomes

```
\bPRE_[^.;,{}()[\]\s]*
```

The phrase `[^blahblah]` means any character except blahblah.